# How to get the value of a corresponding textarea of a button click in codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a set of textareas and `<a>` on a popup window shown as below :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ann</td>
        <td>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <a onclick="update_remarks('+data.sub_ordinates[i].staff_id+')">Submit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Helen</td>
        <td>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a onclick="update_remarks('+data.sub_ordinates[i].staff_id+')">Submit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Inside the `<a>` , I have written the onclick function `update_remarks`. I have included the code for this function below :

```
function update_remarks(staff_id){
    var remarks = document.getElementById("remarks").value;

    $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/regionalzonemanager/regionalzonemanager/delete_staff_lock',{staff_id:staff_id, remarks:remarks},function(data){
        if(data.status==1){
            alert(data.msg);
        }
        else{
 
        }
    },'json');
}
```

The issue is that when I am writing the remarks for the first textarea and in the second textarea and clicking the second row submit button, the first remarks gets inserted into the table. But I what the second remark itself to get inserted into the table. That is , if the remark is entered in a textarea, then when its corresponding button is clicked then that remark should be inserted into the table.

The `delete_staff_lock` this is where I written the insertion code for remarks.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this ?

Comment: I dont see an element with the ```remarks``` ID that you referenced in ```var remarks = document.getElementById("remarks").value;```

Answer (score 0):

Make the ID of your text area to reference your staff_id

```
<tr>
    <td>Ann</td>
    <td>
        <textarea id="remark_001"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
       <a onclick="update_remarks('001')">Submit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then target that ID in your JS

```
function update_remarks(staff_id){
   var remarks = document.getElementById("remarks" + staff_id).value;
}
```